# Custom UIAlertView with Custom Buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uialertview

I need to show a Custom UIAlertView which is going to have an image as a background and two Custom Buttons which will be not the regular UIAlertView Buttons. These buttons will be customized as well and would have their own Artwork.

[image: Sample AlertView]

The example above has a background but I also want to add Custom Button on it.

I am following [this](http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert) guide but I don't think it address the Custom Button handling.

How to do that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't appear to like you overly-customising UIAlertView, and I've heard of a number of occasions where they've declined an app going into the app store because of it.

Because of the extent of customisation you're after, I suggest you create your own new Alert class that animates in and has a background shadow etc with buttons that you can customise the location/look of.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post by Jeff LaMarche to be really helpful in making custom alert views: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html. He goes through the steps of making a custom class since modifying UIAlertView can cause App Store rejection (however he warns that using custom techniques can still cause HIG violations, but I doubt they will for what you're trying to do). By the time you're done, you'll have a custom alert view class that can be added in much the same style as UIAlertView:

> At this point, we're done. We can now
>   use this custom alert view exactly the
>   same way we use UIAlertView:
>
> ```
> CustomAlertView *alert = [[CustomAlertView alloc] init];
> alert.delegate = self;
> [alert show];
> [alert release];
> ```

He creates a custom text input view. Obviously, in your case, you would want to use a different background and instead of adding a text field you'd stick to just the buttons. Since he makes custom buttons in his view too it should cover all your needs, if not more.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apple does not allow subclassing UIAlertView:

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

The easiest way would be to create your own class with similar behavior.

Here's an example:
http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.com/2013/04/creating-custom-alert-view-for-iphone.html